# How to update a JSF java string directly in a javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I want to know how to update a String in my backing bean directly from a Javascript function.

My example tries to call the Javascript function (where the String img will get updated), and then I want to access its new updated content in the save function which is the action event of the button.

This is an extract from the Xhtml file:

```
<Script>
function jsSave(){
     var text=document.getElementById("form:img");
     text.value="New text value";
    }
    </Script>

  <p:commandButton value="Change text" onclick="jsSave();" action="#{backbean.save()}"/> 
  <h:outputText value="#{masterpage_bean.img}" id="img"/>
```

In the backing bean I have this code:

```
   String img;

public String getImg() {
    return img;
}

public void setImg(String img) {
    this.img = img;
}

   public String save(){

    String tex;
    tex=img;

   // I want to do some stuff with the updated value of img here.


 return null;

}
```

Comment: It should be the other way around; update model and then rerender the view based on the updated model. If you want to use JSF, do it the JSF way.

Comment: Gimby, there are indeed scenarios where it is necessary to do it this way around.  The larger picture here is that I want to capture the information from a canvas - which can only be done via a client side script.  I then want to use that information on the server side to save the picture to a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem in my code was a spelling error of the function name (in the Javascript).  So the example in the question actually will work perfectly.  This is a technique that can therefore be used to update the content of a Javabean variable directly from a Javascript function.  One instance where this is very useful is when you want to capture the contents of a canvas and save it in Java to the server.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript functions are located on the client-side, while the managed-beans are on the server-side. This is why you will need either a complete POST, or an AJAX request.

You can use the built-in JSF functionality by nesting a `<f:setPropertyActionListener>` to the `<p:commandButton>`. This will update a specific property in the managed bean with a specific value. For exameple:

```
<p:commandButton value="Change text" action="#{backbean.save()}">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener value="New text value" target="#{masterpage_bean.img}" />
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Kocko that works - but I need to get the value from a call to the jsSave function.  How would I implement that ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using primefaces another really simply way to pass information between javascript and your javabean is the remoteCommand function.